# JSDoc type for multiple vars

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I am writing a JavaScript module and I would like to write a good JSDoc for it. I have a multiple variables defined within single var (`var x = 1, y = functionA;` etc.). One of those variables holds a function reference (may have only 3 choices).

Now my question: is there a way to document it like above, so that my IDE (WebStorm) also recognize the variable type (atm. I get a warning when assigning other function reference to this variable)?

Answer (score 6):

Try using inline doc comments for this, like:

```
var /**Number*/ num = 1, /**String*/ str = "";
```

Comment: it's a valid format - see http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/InlineDocs. And it's supported by WebStorm. Thanks for 2 '-', always glad to help!

Comment: Ah, was looking for single var statements and @typedef. Somebody should accept this answer.

Comment: This actually works by pure luck. Try not defining an initial value for those variables and see how Webstorm is now not aware that you expected a number and a string, respectively.

Comment: it works even without initial values - WebStorm correctly suggests number methods after `num.`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct JSDoc syntax which will work just fine in Webstorm for auto-completion and type checking:

```
let 
    /** @type {Number} */ someNumber, 
    /** @type {String} */ someString;
```

Try setting a string to `someNumber` and see Webstorm complaining about it:

[image]

For functions, you can also specify its parameters and its return value. For instance:

```
/** @type {function(Number, String): Number[]} */
```

Is a function that receives a number as first param, a string as second and returns an array of numbers.

Note: although it works pretty well for auto-completion, currently Webstorm fails to do type checking for functions. For instance, it allows me to do this:

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty old question ;). WebStorm got bajillion updates and now I can't even recreate this issue (or at least can't remember how). Thanks for input anyway :).

Comment: Nevertheless, please consider accepting my contribution, since it correctly answers the original question (which, although old, is still valid). For some reason the other answer has four upvotes, but does not work as intended (I tried in Webstorm).

Comment: Sorry, but I won't do that just because you want more stars on SO. I cannot recreate the original issue so cannot know if this actually solved the original problem. The problem back then wasn't just having primitive types, but function references and updating those (read my entire question, not just half of it). Assigning different function to a variable caused a warning (probably function signatures were different, but I am not sure any more).
Anyway, stop digging the very very old questions and start helping people in need at the moment.

Comment: I am sorry if you understood it that way. I kindly asked you to approve my answer *considering you agreed it answered your question*. My sincere intent was to just answer the question, no matter how old it is. The question is still open and the only answer so far was incorrect, so why not give a proper answer?

Comment: And yes, I answered what you asked. Both the multiple-var declaration and how to document a function type. When you say "I cannot reproduce the issue anymore", that's not true. That's easy to reproduce in Webstorm. But if you don't want to bother testing my answer, that's fine to me, really! Better to just leave it there for others that may have the same doubt.

Comment: No it is not easy to reproduce this issue as I have tried to create a variable with function assigned, and then reassign a different function to it (with different signature), but it did not show any error or warning, so they probably changed it in IDE itself. This means I cannot accept any answer as either working or not.

Comment: Hm, you're right. I just tested it here and assigning a new function with a different signature doesn't really make Webstorm complain, even if I document it with the signature I expect it to have. Good catch. I'll add this information to my answer and hopefully some day they will fix this behavior.

Comment: Added a note to my answer. Well, I don't know what to do with this. Your question title does not match what we're discussing now, so possible suggestions are 1) improve the title, 2) close the question since what you actually want (which is not what the title says) is currently broken in Webstorm or 3) leave it be. Anyway, thanks for discussing it :-) Cheers